# Memory leak when resizing dynamic array

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic

Here's my code:

```
template<class T> class Test 
{
    public:
    int Size = 0;
    int Length = 0;
T* Items; 

    Test() {}

~Test() 
    {  
    delete [] Items; 
    }

    void Append(const T& newItem) 
{
        if (Size + 1 >= Length)
    {   
        Length += 250;
            T* old = Items; 
        Items = new T[Length + 250]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) 
           Items[i] = old[i];
            delete [] old; 
        }

        Items[Size] = newItem;  
    Size++;
} 
};

Test<int> test;
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
   test.Append(i);
```

I'm populating the dynamic array with 500000 integers which must take just 1-2Mb but it takes about 30Mb. There's no problem if i set the initial size to 500000(i.e. no resizing occurring). The grow value(250) seems to affect the memory somehow, if it's larger(for example 1000) then the memory usage is pretty low. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post the actual code? I don't think this snippet shows where the problem lies.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: What "problem" are you talking about? The question mentions "memory leak"... Where and how do you see that leak? What does "must take just 1-2Mb but it takes about 20Mb" mean? How do you determine how much memory it takes? The code you posted has no problems, so it doesn't really help to understand anything.

Comment: No wonder you have a memory leak; you’re using `new[]`.

Comment: You do know `std::vector` was made specifically for this purpose right?

Comment: I guess you `delete [] Items;` somewhere else?

Comment: Is there statement count = new_size in your function?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you are reallocating an array, you do not want to modify the actual array until the very last second (to maintain exception safety):

```
T* temp = new T[new_size]; 
// assume count is the previous size and count < new_size
std::copy(Items, Items + count, temp);
std::swap(temp, Items);
delete [] temp;
```

Aside from that, there is nothing visible in your code that would cause a memory leak.

The extra size can possibly be due to other optimizations (being turned off) and/or debugging symbols being turned on.  What compiler options are you using (and what compiler)?  It should be noted that extra size is not necessarily an indication of a memory leak.  Have you run this in a debugger or memory profiler which found a leak?

It should also be noted that `std::vector` does all of this for you.

Comment: I'm using gcc, g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.exe

Comment: @JulesBianqi Can you post more of your code (specifically that dealing with your memory management)?  What you have posted only has the potential exception safety issue.

Comment: This is basically the only function that deals with memory management. I think the problem is the "Items[i] = Old[i]", when i comment that line everything seems fine.

Comment: What does the whole function look like ... and do you ever `delete [] Items;` anywhere else?

Comment: No, i don't delete Items anywhere else.

Comment: In that case, `Items` is leaked (but assuming it is in use for the entire length of the program, that would be poor practice, but not a degradation in performance).  Unless you have some need (e.g. a school assignment) to write your own dynamic array, I would recommend you stick with `std::vector` (or at the very least, write it using vector first, and then convert it - it will likely show you where your problem lies).

Comment: @JulesBianqi And the `Items[i] = old[i];` line is simply copying the items from the "old" array into the new one.  If your `T`s are some form of `int` for this example, there is nothing there that would cause a leak.  If your `T`s are a custom class with dynamic memory management within them, you could have some logical flaw in that class that is leaking memory, but you have not shown that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you're going to segfault more so than leak memory due to the fact that calling `delete` or `delete[]` on a non-NULL, but previously deallocated, pointer is a Bad Thing. Also, I don't believe this is your real code, because what you posted won't compile.

When you `delete` a pointer, always set it to NULL afterwards. It's good practice to initialize to NULL as well. Let's fix up your code to make sure we don't call `delete` on previously deallocated pointers. Also, let's initialize our pointer to NULL.

Your misuse of memory probably stems from the following lines of code:

```
Length += 250;
T* old = Items; 
Items = new T[Length + 250];
```

Notice that you increment Length by 250, but then allocate Length+250 more elements? Let's fix that, too.

```
template<class T> 
class Test 
{
public:
    int Size;
    int Length;
    T* Items; 

    Test() : Size(0), Length(0), Items(NULL){}

    ~Test() {
       if (Items != NULL)
          delete [] Items; 
    }

    void Append(const T& newItem) 
    {
        if (Size + 1 >= Length)
        {   
           Length += 250;
           T* old = Items; 
           Items = new T[Length]; 
           for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) 
              Items[i] = old[i];
           delete [] old;
           old = NULL;
        }

        Items[Size] = newItem;  
        Size++;
    } 
};

int main(){
    Test<int> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
       test.Append(i);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's good to know these things. But can someone help me with the memory usage issue? 500000 integers = 46Mb. Someone asked what's so strange about that... Task Manager says that my app uses 46Mb. That's anything but normal. There is nothing else in the .cpp file i'm compiling, really. Only the code that AndyG posted in this answer. I'm using gcc, latest version.  Again, if i change the grow value to a bigger number(for example 500) the memory usage is only 3mb which seems normal for the dynamic array i'm populating.

Comment: You, or whoever told you that 46 MB is normal, need to recheck their math. Typical int is 4 bytes. 500,000 * 4 = 2,000,000 bytes = 2 MB (using the definition for 1 MB as 10^6 bytes, not 2^20 bytes). When I run the above code, I see memory peak out around 2.5 MB, which is normal considering the fact that at some point you have 2 arrays, one of which you are copying data into before you delete the first one.